# How to Window.Open inside a jQuery Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have my Modal Div as:

```
 <div id="dialog-modal" title="Open File">
        <img alt="progress" src="images/ajax-loader.gif"/>
  </div>
```

On Click of Button I am able to see Modal and then see the progress icon.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $('#button1').click(function () {
             $('#dialog-modal').dialog("open");
         });
         $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
             autoOpen: false,
             height: 140,
             modal: true,
         });
     });
 </script>
```

But How can I do a operation or function on Load of Modal Window??

Let's say , I want to download a file from server , when the modal window appears (..showing the progress icon)

Comment: how to get data? use ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook into the `dialogopen` function:

```
$( "#dialog-modal" ).on( "dialogopen", function( event, ui ) {
    console.log('Wayhay!!');
    window.open("http://www.google.com");
} );
```

See jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Y63f/1/

Further info here:

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open